# How to create a dynamic method for deactivate and activate module

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing a system. In my system there are modules called Event and Announcement, both of these have deactivate and activate dropdown button. To reduce the redundancy of the method, I would like to create a dynamic method for this.

But Having difficulty in which ID is this come from? Is it from Event or Announcement? I know you've to use a route and I already done that part

Question: How to determine the ID if it is for Event/Announcement?

NOTE: my schema

```
Event table
id
event_title
event_description
event_date

Announcement table
id
announcement_title
announcement_description
announcement_date
```

In my controller, I used parameter to pass it to my model to make it dynamic. The order of my parameter:table, data, condition

**Controller**

```
public function deactivate()
    {
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);


        $where = array('id' => $id);
        $update_status = array(
                'status'    => 'Inactive'
            );
        //$this->Crud_model->update('event',$update_status,$where);
        //redirect('administrator/event/');
    }
    public function activate()
    {
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $where = array('id' => $id);
        $update_status = array(
                'status'    => 'Active'
            );
        //$this->Crud_model->update('co',$update_status,$where);
        //redirect('administrator/branch/'. $session_location);
    }
```

**View**

```
<td><div class="dropdown">
                  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Action
                  </button>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                     <?php if($row->status == 'Active'){?>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= base_url().'administrator/deactivate/'. $row->id?>">Deactivate</a>
                     <?php } else { ?>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= base_url().'administrator/activate/'. $row->id?>">Activate</a>
                    <?php }?>

                     <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= base_url().'administrator/delete/'. $row->id?>">Delete</a>
                  </div>
              </div></td>
```

**Route**

```
$route['admnistrator/deactivate/'] = 'administrator/deactivate/$1';
$route['admnistrator/activate/'] = 'administrator/activate/$1';
```

**Model**

```
public function update($table,$data,$where=""){
        if($where!="") {
                $this->db->where($where);
        }

        $result = $this->db->update($table,$data);
        if ($result) {
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: your question is difficult to understand, what do you want to achieve, how is schema related to routes, how are the 2 schema tables linked? Is announcement linked to event, etc. please try to rephrase your question

Comment: So you're not extending the model in order to specify its schema? You're just using the model itself and asign it a table? If so you should store the type/table with it and read that variable when you want to know the type.

Comment: Just passing ID is not enough to identify your schema.

Comment: @vickel I just display the columns of my 2 tables. There is no connection between the two tables.

Comment: @Hek mat Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Passing your table name and id with parameters inside the controller like this

```
public function deactivate($table = '',$id = '')
{
    $where = array('id' => $id);
    $update_status = array(
        'status'    => 'Inactive'
    );
    //$this->Crud_model->update($table,$update_status,$where);
    //redirect('administrator/event/');
}
public function activate($table = '',$id = '')
{
    $where = array('id' => $id);
    $update_status = array(
        'status'    => 'Active'
    );
    //$this->Crud_model->update($table,$update_status,$where);
    //redirect('administrator/branch/'. $session_location);
}
```

And in the html dropdown change the href of your anchor tag():

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <?php if($row->status == 'Active'){?>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= base_url().'administrator/deactivate/{event/announcement}'. $row->id?>">Deactivate</a>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= base_url().'administrator/activate/{event/announcement}'. $row->id?>">Activate</a>
    <?php }?>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= base_url().'administrator/delete/'. $row->id?>">Delete</a>
</div>
```

Also if needed change your routes to:

```
$route['admnistrator/deactivate/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'administrator/deactivate/$1/$2';
$route['admnistrator/activate/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'administrator/activate/$1/$2';
```

Comment: Wow man, I didnt know that you can use 2 parameters in routes

Answer (score 0):

change your scheme, if possible to:

```
One table
id
kind
title
description
date
```

where e.g. kind=1 could be event and kind=2 could be announcement and return the values (id's) you want with a `where kind=1` clause in your query